# is "I bring that statement to contest" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, transitive-verbs

My question is if the sentence

> "I bring that statement to contest"

is grammatically correct and in a logical sequence of words that can be understood. Also, I would like to know if that is a correct way to use *contest* as a transitive verb when meaning to "To dispute" or "Call into question".

Comment: If you mean to use _contest_ as a verb, the build-up of your sentence is simular to "I bring that statement to fly", which seems strange. What's wrong with _I contest that statement_?

Comment: I agree it does sound kind of strange. Although to be honest I thought _I contest that statement_ was a better way to phrase it but I was just carious if it could be used the other way.
Thanks you for your response @oerkelens

Comment: "I bring that statement to contest" may be grammatically correct, but it is neither idiomatic nor particularly sensible. Instead you might write, "I wish to bring that statement into question," which keeps your meaning and still uses the verb "to bring."

Comment: Among other things, the statement can be interpreted at least two different ways, probably more, and we have no idea if you are getting the meaning you intend, since you have provided **no context.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the construction *bring to contest* is not a valid usage meaning 'dispute'. *I contest that statement* is the right way to put it, especially if you're contesting someone else's statement.
I get the impression you're thinking of a statement that you are 'bringing' into the discussion especially for the purpose of contesting it. In that case, you can't use *I contest that statement*, and you would have to say something like

> I bring that statement up in order to contest it.